# What does the plot/graph of an associative function on the unit square look like?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, associativity

I have a function $f(x,y):[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$. Let's say that I plot the function as a heat map (that is, I color each pixel in the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ according to the value of the function at that point)

I'm interested in knowing what the plot would look like given that the function is associative: $f(x,f(y,z))=f(f(x,y),z)$ for all $x,y,z$.

Commutative functions $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ have a plot which is mirror-symmetric along the diagonal of the square. Is there, similarly, some simple visual property that characterizes all associative functions (and only them)?

(To make it simpler, we may assume that we are talking about a "regular-enough" function, e.g. piecewise continuous or something like that, so that it would make sense to speak about its plot)

Comment: Even for finite domains (i.e. $f:X\times X\to X$ for some finite $X$), it's not really that easy to say how one could "look" at the resulting table and tell that it's associative. At the very least, it's not something you can just "spot" the way you can spot a mirror symmetry.

Comment: I don't think there can be a simple visual property if you plot the function with a heat map. The reason is that the value $f(x, y)$ is visualized by the _color_ of the pixel $(x, y)$, but needs to be interpreted as the _coordinate_ of a pixel in the expression $f(f(x, y), z)$.